# A Java Program using socket class to connect to another ip and port if one is not reachable

Tags: java, sockets

**A Java Program using socket class to connect to another ip and port if 
one is not reachable ? **

**Please help ! **

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try to tell it more clearly

Comment: Is this some homework? try yourself doing it first

Answer (score 0):

Just go through your logic once again.How to connect to not-reachable node.You have to make it reachable first.Use "ping 192.168.1.101" (instead ,provide your Ip address) in command prompt.